# Using distinct() with a vector of column names

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, distinct

I have a question using `distinct()` from dplyr on a tibble/data.frame. From the documentation it is clear that you can use it by naming explicitely the column names. I have a data frame with >100 columns and want to use the funtion just on a subset. My intuition said I put the column names in a vector and use it as an argument for distinct. But distinct uses only the first vector element

Example on iris:

```
data(iris)
library(dplyr)


exclude.columns <- c('Species', 'Sepal.Width')
distinct_(iris, exclude.columns)
```

This is different from

```
exclude.columns <- c('Sepal.Width', 'Species')
distinct_(iris, exclude.columns)
```

I think distinct is not made for this operation. Another option would be to subset the data.frame then use distinct and join again with the excluded columns. But my question is if there is another option using just one function?

Comment: You can just list the columns inside `distinct` and use the `.keep_all = TRUE` argument. Or you can use `distinct_at` from `dplyr v0.8` onwards.

Comment: @arg0naut: The problem is not the listing, it is that distinct() operates only on the first vector element and not on both as expected. distinct_at() was not in the documentation, I will give it a try.

Comment: Try also `distinct(iris, !!! syms(exclude.columns))`

Comment: Thx, this should work!

Comment: @arg0naut91, could you consider posting your `distinct(iris, !!! syms(exclude.columns))` comment as an answer? It is very helpful and should be more visible.

Answer (score 3):

As suggested in my comment, you could also try:

```
data(iris)
library(dplyr)

exclude.columns <- c('Species', 'Sepal.Width')

distinct(iris, !!! syms(exclude.columns))
```

Output (first 10 rows):

```
   Sepal.Width    Species
1          3.5     setosa
2          3.0     setosa
3          3.2     setosa
4          3.1     setosa
5          3.6     setosa
6          3.9     setosa
7          3.4     setosa
8          2.9     setosa
9          3.7     setosa
10         4.0     setosa
```

However, that was suggested more than 2 years ago. A more proper usage of latest `dplyr` functionalities would be:

```
distinct(iris, across(all_of(exclude.columns)))
```

It is not entirely clear to me whether you would like to keep only the `exclude.columns` or actually exclude them; if the latter then you just put minus in front i.e. `distinct(iris, across(-all_of(exclude.columns)))`.

Answer (score 0):

Your objective sounds unclear. Are you trying to get all distinct rows across all columns except `$Species` and `$Sepal.Width`? If so, that doesn't make sense.

Let's say two rows are the same in all other variables except for $Sepal.Width. Using `distinct()` in the way you described would throw out the second row because it was not distinct from the first. Except that it was in the column you ignored.

You need to rethink your objective and whether it makes sense.

If you are just worried about duplicate rows, then

```
data %>%
  distinct(across(everything()))
```

will do the trick.